# suggested architecture / frameworks for collaborative mobile planning app?

Tags: mobile, web-applications, architecture, frameworks, collaboration

I'm designing an app which needs to have some collaboration functionality. So 1 to many users can edit certain attributes of an event they plan together. e.g. the main-admin can change the title, picture etc. while all admin-users could change the date for example.

I would like to get some ideas how one would approach this in the modern world. Are there fancy frameworks etc.

Q: Is the best way storing it centraly on some server or would some peer to peer data storage work?

Q: My gut-feeling is that a web-application would probably be the easiest way, where people work on the object stored on the server instead of trying to sync a local copy with some central repository.
Is this correct?

Q: Are there mobile frameworks which could do the syncing, locking etc for me?

Thank you for some hints and suggestions. I know the questions are a bit broad, but I'm looking for directions not finished solutions. Thank you.
Kind regards
Fred

Comment: collaboration meaning more-or-less real time visibility of a collaborator's changes? Or .... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1a) There is no "best" way without a metric for better/best. But yes, having a server is almost certainly simpler, which is probably part of 'best' for most of us.

1b) Actually, there is always a server. Even p2p systems have clients and servers, it's just that every node is both a server and a client.

2) Yes, a web app would certain give you a lot of plumbing for free, & would probably be fastest/cheapest route to a working app. An alternative would be an olde worlde client/server database. A shinier approach might be mobile apps which use a webservice to communicate with a central server.

3) databases do that. But actually, if you use a web app it's probably not hard.

Analogies:

- Apart from web apps, version control systems do exactly what you've
  just described. they even do offline editting and subsequent merging.
- Straightforward CRUD applications against a database also do what
  you've just described.

But perhaps I'm under-estimating what you mean by collaboration?